# Подключение к удаленной Mysql: MySQL server has gone away

Tags: php, mysql

Добрый день.
Недавно только начал изучать mysql, поэтому. периодически возникают сложности, который я до сего момента мог сам решить. Но сейчас прошу Вашей помощи.

Я пытаюсь соединиться с mysql сервером из php, админ мне выдал айпи, логин, пароль, имя базы.
Php файлик выглядит так:

```
$hostname = '192.168.1.20:1433';
$username = "t";
$password = "t";
$dbName = "insy";
mysql_connect($hostname,$username,$password) OR DIE(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($dbName) or die(mysql_error());
$query = "SELECT * FROM `insy` WHERE 1;";
$result=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
echo "works!";
mysql_close();
```

При выполнении страничка долго висит, и в конце концов возвращает:

```
Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: MySQL server has gone away in N:\home\192.168.1.19\www\phlib.php on line 12

Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Error while reading greeting packet. PID=1908 in N:\home\192.168.1.19\www\phlib.php on line 12

Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: MySQL server has gone away in N:\home\192.168.1.19\www\phlib.php on line 12
MySQL server has gone away
```

12 строка - это:

```
mysql_connect($hostname,$username,$password) OR DIE(mysql_error());
```

Пробовал в администраровании ODBC Sql Server источник данных - с теми же параметрами нормально создается, видятся базы.

Подскажите, что я делаю не так?

**UPD:** все машины на Windows.

Заранее благодарю!

Comment: Стоит денвер или сам ставил mysql server?

порт просто какой-то нестандартный 1433.

Comment: на сервере куда коннекчусь - стоит стоит просто mysql сервер. Машина с которой коннекчусь - с денвером.
порт - рабочий, телнетом на него можно подцепиться, в отличие от 3306.

Comment: 1433 - это стандартный порт MS Sql сервера, может там реально другой сервак висит? phpmyadmin коннектится к нему?

Comment: Подскажите, а как майадмином подключиться к удаленному серверу?

Comment: ``http://localhost/phpmyadmin/setup/index.php`` там настройте подключение...

Comment: А я смеялся много с этой ошибки))

    SELECT ... FROM ... // 2 rows, N sec
    SELECT ... JOIN ... JOIN ... // 5 rows, N sec
    SELECT ... JOIN ... JOIN ... JOIN ... JOIN ... WHERE ... AND ... AND ... GROUP BY ... LIMIT // Mysql сервер обиделся и ушел =(

Answer (score 1):

Проверьте, что у вас разрешены удаленные соединения, можно при помощи следующей команды:

```
%netstat -an | grep 3306
tcp4 0 0                  *.3306                *.*    LISTEN 
%
```

Если вы видите эту строчку  значит удаленный доступ у вас открыт

ЭТО для FreeBSD, я просто не знаю на чем у вас сервер!
Скажите ось, я команду перепишу.

**Windows**

```
netstat -na | find "3306"
```

**LINUX**

```
netstat -na | grep 3306
```

Comment: машины на windows.
проверять на какой из машин? к к оторой коннекчусь? Не получится, у меня к ней доступа нет.
Вот результат с моей машины:
C:\Documents and Settings\omg>netstat -na | find "3306"
  TCP    0.0.0.0:3306           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING

Comment: какой смысл запускать на своей машине...

Comment: Ну тогда все вопросы к вашему админу...

Comment: но ведь если телнетом к нему нельзя соединиться - знаит порт не слушается. смысл нетстата?.

Comment: ну тогда да! смысла нету от netstat? просто выше в комментарии было вами написано "телнетом на него можно подцепиться, в отличие от 3306", netstat можно для любого порта, я в качестве примера привел порт 3306